# Sending and receiving faxes

Tags: php, web-applications

Hi I need to build a web application which can send and receive Faxes.
Can some one mention some of the articles/web page where I can refer to get more details about it?

Also I'm posting this to PHP folks assuming that this can be done in PHP but if you feel else is appropriate please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/php

Just from a quick Google search... I don't have any personal experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a fax is not a function built in to PHP. You'll need to use an external service for this.

[Google "send fax online"](https://www.google.com/?q=send%20fax%20online) and start reading.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to integrate it with PHP is to use a Mail 2 Fax gateway there are plenty of services out there.

Tipically you just need to send an email with with a pdf attachment to a particulaur address like [faxnumber]@fax.fax2mail.com ( 390302121212@fax.fax2mail.com )

I've integrated it with php and java (both 2 seperate application) for my firm.